# C problem with passing pointer to struct to function

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, structure

I have a problem passing structure pointer to a function with `fscanf()`.

Here's my struct:

```
typedef struct {
  int health;
  int y;
  int z;
} save;
```

in `main` I have:

```
save save = { 0 }; //init with zeros
loadgame(&save);
health = save.health;
```

and my function `loadgame()` looks like that:

```
bool loadgame(save* save) {
  FILE* fptr;
  fptr = fopen("savegame.txt", "r");
  if (fptr == NULL)
    return 0;
  fscanf(fptr, "health= %d", save->health);
  return 1;
};
```

my `savegame.txt` file has line:

```
health= 5
```

and my function doesn't change `save->health`, after finish of this function my health equals zero.

I tried to do my function like that and it also has the same solution in function `loadgame()` I changed

```
fscanf(fptr, "health= %d", save-health);
```

to

```
fscanf(fptr, "health= %d", &(save-health));
```

Comment: and i also tried to pass a normal structure (save save) and loadgame(save), it also doesn't work, the point is that i'm trying to change values of my structure in my function

Comment: //Sorry for wrong thread name, just changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fscanf` needs a pointer so it knows where to save the value.
Other than that your code has a bunch of other small issues.
I have addressed those in the comments below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
typedef struct {
    int health;
    int y;
    int z;
}save_tp;

//using the same name for a typedef and a variable is a bad idea;
//typedef struct{...} foo; foo foo; prevents you from declaring other varibles of type foo
//as the foo variable overshadows the foo typedef name;
//better give types a distinct name


bool loadgame(save_tp* save){
    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("savegame.txt", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        return false;
    bool r = (1==fscanf(fptr, "health= %d", &save->health)); //needs an address + may fail
    fclose(fptr); //need to close the file or you'd be leaking a file handle
    return r;
} //shouldn't have a semicolon here

int main(void)
{
    save_tp save={0};
    if (!loadgame(&save)) perror("nok");
    else printf("ok, health=%d\n", save.health);
}
```

Comment: @P__J__ Was just sticking to the OP's style where I considered it OK. But sure, why not.

Answer (score 2):

`fscanf(fptr, "health= %d", save->health);` -> `fscanf(fptr, "health= %d", &save->health);`

Here you have working verison to play with https://godbolt.org/z/5CuZwR

As in my example **always** check the result of the `scanf`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your fscanf is passing the value of save->health instead of it's address.

You need to do

```
fscanf(fptr, "health= %d", &save->health);
```

Since -> has precedence over & this will give you the address of the health member.